# How do I make an iFrame slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to make an iFrame slideshow, which will show some websites in an iframe after 20 seconds frequently. I have tried [innerFade plugin](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/), but it doesn't work in iFrames. Does any body have any code samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a demo for this a long while back.  This may get you going it the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dazE/7/show

and source of course here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dazE/7/

Comment: hi Joseph Marikle, thanks but i'm a new programmer...i need a simple script that will create a slideshow of some websites in an iframe after 20 seconds frequently...can you give a example/code of such script..Thanks

Comment: @rakibtg unfortunately that's all I have atm. :S  If you can use the one I linked, I don't mind.  You would have to delete and add the sites you need with the dialogue that pops up at the start, but other than that, I've not ever hear of a script that does that.